# How to create a time counter using C# in Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, timer

I would like to create a time counter to my Unity 3D game.

I've already tried to use Time.time but I can't reset the timer without resetting the whole game. timeSinceLevelLoad doesn't work for me either because reloading the level is required.

I've tried to use Time.deltaTime inside the FixedUpdate but I feel like the time isn't right. The reason I can't reload the game or the level is that I made my machine state to be one scene only:

```
switch (currentState) {

        case GameStates.START:{
            player.position = startPositionPlayer;
            currentState = GameStates.WAITGAME;
            timeScore.renderer.enabled = false;
        }
            break;

        case GameStates.WAITGAME:{
            player.position = startPositionPlayer;
            timeScore.renderer.enabled = false;
        }
            break;

        case GameStates.INGAME:{
            time = Time.time;
            timeScore.text = time.ToString();
        }
            break;  

        case GameStates.GAMEOVER:{
            currentState = GameStates.RANKING;
            player.position = startPositionPlayer;
            enemy.position = startPositionEnemy;
            timeScore.renderer.enabled = false;
        }
            break;

        case GameStates.RANKING:{
            player.position = startPositionPlayer;
            enemy.position = startPositionEnemy;
            timeScore.renderer.enabled = false;
        }
            break;
        }
    }
```

So my whole game runs in a single scene. This function is used to restart the game using GameStates.INGAME:

```
public void StartGame(){
    time = 0f;
    timeScore.renderer.enabled = true;
    currentState = GameStates.INGAME;
}
```

My question is: **How can I create a progressive time counter that I can reset without the need to reload the game, scene or level?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the start of the game you save the `startTime` then you decide how long a round should last, `roundTime`.

Example:

```
startTime = Time.time;
roundTime = 1000f; // seconds.
```

Then you can simply check when time has passed.

```
function Update ()
{
    if (Time.time - startTime >= roundTime)
    {
        // Game ended, restart.
        startTime = Time.time;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `StopWatch` instead. They are easy to use:

```
Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
stopWatch.Start();

//Your game

stopWatch.Stop();
// Get the elapsed time as a TimeSpan value.
TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
```

In your code replace the code which launch your counter:

```
/*
 * Replace
 */
time = 0f;
timeScore.renderer.enabled = true;
/* 
 * By
 */
time = new Stopwatch();
time.Start();
```

And the code who stop it:

```
/*
 * Replace
 */
time = Time.time;
timeScore.text = time.ToString();
/* 
 * By
 */
stopWatch.Stop();
timeScore.text = stopWatch.Elapsed.ToString();
```

see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.elapsed(v=vs.110).aspx for more informations about StopWatch

Answer (score 0):

You can use a private variable to track time.

```
public float RoundLength = 30f;

private float timeKeeper;
private bool isPaused = false;
private bool gameIsOver = false;

void Start() {
    this.timeKeeper = this.RoundLength;
}

void Update() {
    if (!this.isPaused && !this.gameIsOver) {
        this.timeKeeper -= Time.deltaTime;

        if (this.timeKeeper < 0f) DoGameOver();
    }
}

void DoGameOver() {
    this.gameIsOver = true;
}
```

You can set or reset that float whenever you need to.